# Can't connect to mongolab form shell

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect to mongolab via shell. I get a code from lab.

```
mongo ds023432.mlab.com:23432/somecol -u fakeusername -p fakepass123
```

Of course i created a db user on mongolab site. However When i call the above command I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6 Enter password: 
connecting to: ds023432.mlab.com:23432/somecol
2016-05-16T17:55:04.290+0200 E -        [main] file [fakepass123] doesn't exist
failed to load: fakepass123
```

So far I am able to connect only via driver. And I am using Arch linux
What am I missing?

Comment: Try using a 3.0.x version of the mongo shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Arch Linux as well with `mongo` client version `3.2.6` and have the same issue.

I would assume it is a client - server incompatibility (since my java application can connect with its driver)

To solve the issue I've installed **[robomongo](https://robomongo.org/)** via

```
yaourt -S robomongo-bin --noconfirm
```

[image]

Notes:

- Follow [these steps](http://www.ostechnix.com/install-yaourt-arch-linux/) to get `yaourt` if you don't already have it
- I am not affiliated with robomongo - it's just a solution for the problem I was facing

Comment: Okay, so I used the same approach. I only installed MongoChef, as Robomongo was crashing. There is plenty of talk on that on forums. Some say it might be due to mongolabs switch to mongo 3, other say its the UI thing. I'm using I3, so i don't know. Hey, the important thing is we're connected. :) Thanks for your help!